# Getting an image url from jsp to ajax without jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

i have this function in javascript, that i want to show me a diferrent image every time:It gets this image from a jsp(that connects with database through a method)

function myFunction(eventId) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function(){     
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("imgevent").style.background = "url('xmlhttp.responseText')  repeat scroll 0 0 / cover ";
    }else{
            document.getElementById("imgevent").innerHTML = "Waiting for getting Picture";
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","pictures.jsp?e="+eventId,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Here is the jsp code:

```
<% 
    String ev = request.getParameter("e");
    int eventt = Integer.parseInt(ev);
    Ev e = new Ev();
    String img = e.getPicture(eventt);
    response.setContentType("image/jpg");  
%>
```

I am not sure how **right is the way that response** server(jsp) back to client(javascript)
(The method that gets the url from database is right)

Answer (score 0):

First, use the correct content type for the image. It is `image/jpeg` with a second `e`.

Then: Don't use XMLHttpRequest.

You want to display an image in the page. You don't need to have direct access to the raw image data in JS for that.

```
document.getElementById("imgevent").style.background =
    "url(pictures.jsp?e=" + eventId + ") repeat scroll 0 0 / cover";
```

Comment: that means that I dont have  to use xmlhttp.open("GET","eventPictures.jsp?eventId="+eventId,true);xmlhttp.send(); ?

Comment: Yes. Hence "Don't use XMLHttpRequest"

Comment: ! I wasn t so sure about the jsp and the use of response.setContentType("image/jpeg"); . I hope it works your  suggestion, thanks!

Comment: function myFunction(eventId) {
 
 document.getElementById("imgevent").style.background ="url(eventPictures.jsp?eventId=" + eventId + ") repeat scroll 0 0 / cover";
         
} I tried what you said but still doesnt work.. maybe is it wrong that the String img  that i get from database is like this 'img/event1.jpg' ?

Comment: @maria — Are you saying that the output of your JSP is a string and not an image? So it should have the content-type `text/plain`?

Comment: yes, it is String, but again it doesnt work String ev = request.getParameter("eventId");
 int eventt = Integer.parseInt(ev);
 
 EventDAO eventdao = new EventDAO();
 String imgurl = eventdao.getPicture(eventt);
 
 response.setContentType("text/plain");

Comment: My answer was based on the assumption that the output of the JSP with the content-type which said was an image … was an image.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need an async request, you can simply add the url as source:

```
<img id="myimg" src="pictures.jsp?e=0">
<script>
var img;
window.onload=function(){
img=document.getElementById("myimg");
 }
 function changeimg(eid){
 img.src="pictures.jsp?e="+eid;
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: i already have in jsp   onload="myFunction(<%=eventId%>). i will try your way. Thanks!